# Is there a way to write database rules through Firestore's REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to initialize a Firestore database with a script and so I would like to write to the database rules through a REST API rather than manually.

There is a REST API to edit Firebase Realtime Database security rules. There is also a REST API to interface with Firestore in general. However, I have not found a REST API to edit Cloud Firestore database security rules.

Comment: what is ur use case? overwrite em all? or just a portion? I dont think there is a REST API to achieve this, the closer thing is to use the cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to use the `firebase-tools` node module, which you may already know from using it as the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

By [signing in with `login:ci`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#command_reference), you can then call various commands from within your CI system, including [deploying your Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deployment) by [running or calling `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#use_the_firebase_cli).